# Wrong hyphenation between french quotes

Tags: hyphenation, quotation

I'm transcribing a book in Italian and I can't get proper hyphenation with the words in quotation marks.

If I write:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a5paper, margin={15mm,20mm}]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[greek,italian]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\usepackage[
    left = \flqq{},% 
    right = \frqq{},% 
    leftsub = \flq{},% 
    rightsub = \frq{} %
]{dirtytalk}

\begin{document}

Vi sono medici che distinguono i diversi tipi di pericolosità a seconda
del fine dell'«oggetto» medico: se è giovane o se è vecchio.

Vi sono medici che distinguono i diversi tipi di pericolosità a seconda
del fine dell'\say{oggetto} medico: se è giovane o se è vecchio.

Vi sono medici che distinguono i diversi tipi di pericolosità a seconda
del fine dell'\flqq{}oggetto\frqq{} medico: se è giovane o se è vecchio.

Vi sono medici che distinguono i diversi tipi di pericolosità a seconda
del fine dell'oggetto medico: se è giovane o se è vecchio.

\end{document}
```

I get:

[image: actual result]

whereas I would like to get:

[image: desired result]

Even using `\hyphenation{«og-get-to»}` I do not get the desired result.

Is there any solution?

Comment: Although I cannot answer your question, for the benefit of those who can answer: Do you need to apply the hyphenation to just one line (or a few selected lines), or do you need it to be applied automatically wherever it occurs? There are brute-force methods for doing the first of these.

Comment: Please, provide a minimal working example (MWE).

Comment: This probably won't help, but the quotes really shouldn't be put into the `\hyphenation{...}` entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tell LaTeX that hyphenation is possible in the word following the open guillemets.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[greek,italian]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[
    left = \flqq\nobreak\hspace{0pt}, 
    right = \frqq, 
    leftsub = \flq\nobreak\hspace{0pt}, 
    rightsub = \frq
]{dirtytalk}

\begin{document}

Vi sono medici che distinguono i diversi tipi di pericolosità a seconda
del fine dell'\say{oggetto} medico: se è giovane o se è vecchio.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It results in an error `Argument of \@firstoftwo has an extra }.`

Comment: @fusion3k Only if you use an outdated TeX distribution such as TeX Live 2021 or earlier. Add `\noexpand` in front of `\hspace`, until you update your TeX system.

Comment: OK, it works. Many thanks. Anyway, my version is 3.141592653 (TeX Live 2022). Without `\noexpand` I get error also on Overleaf.